# Finding where class constructors are called in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, you can focus on class XXX and press Ctrl+Alt+H, to get a call hierarchy showing everywhere that `new XXX(...)` is called.

In IntelliJ IDEA, I can only do this on each constructor separately, and I can't do it at all on the default constructor (invisible).

Is there a way in IDEA that I'm missing? (Ultimate 12.1.3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly - one way you can do this is to select the classname (instead of an individual constructor name) and press Alt+F7 (Find usages).

This will find all usages of that class - the "Found Usages" window that will be displayed is split up into expandable sections, one of which will be "new instance creation".

**NOTE**: if you can't see a `New instance creation` grouping, makes sure `Group by usage type` is enabled (the "funnel" looking icon in the screen shot below).

In IDEA 2017.2, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I checked Find usages, clearly I didn't check it well enough :)

Comment: My favorite is Ctrl+Alt+F7 which gives you more or less the same information in a popup instead of a window pane.

Comment: Doesn't have "new instance creation" grouping nowadays

Comment: @maba is it possible to "group by usage type" in the popup? I realize your comment is a few years old, maybe things changed. Unrelated, for Linux the shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+7 (Ctrl+Alt+F7 would switch to another console).